# Hide buttons in cell by other button press uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

Wondering how can I get all items of each cell in `UITableView`. My problem is that I want to hide 2 buttons in cell when third is selected.

[image: example of my cell]

When I press on button 1, button 2 and 3 must be hidden. What I tried to do for that (in cellForRowAtIndexPath) :

```
AVMMovieButton *settings = (AVMMovieButton *)[cell viewWithTag:228];
[settings addTarget:self action:@selector(selectSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
settings.tag = indexPath.row;

AVMMovieButton *playButton = (AVMMovieButton *)[cell viewWithTag:134];
[playButton setStore:oneItem];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playButton.tag = indexPath.row;

AVMMovieButton *down = (AVMMovieButton *)[cell viewWithTag:282];

AVMMovieButton *del = (AVMMovieButton *)[cell viewWithTag:161];

[settings  setSelected:!settings.isSelected];
if (settings.isSelected) 
{
    NSLog(@"SELECTED!");

    down.hidden = YES;
    del.hidden = YES;
    downLabel.hidden = YES;
    delLabel.hidden = YES;

   // [self performSelector:@selector(playButtonShow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    playButton.hidden = NO;     
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"UNSELECTED!");

    playButton.hidden = YES;
    down.hidden = NO;
    del.hidden = NO;
    downLabel.hidden = NO;
    delLabel.hidden = NO;

    NSLog(@"play button %d",playButton.hidden);
}
```

and then I added method for selecting my "settings" button:

```
-(void)selectSettings:(AVMMovieButton *)sender
{
    [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
    NSLog(@"you just select button");
}
```

but it doesn't work!

Actually `NSLog(@"you just select button");` works, but buttons never hides.

What should I do to get my buttons and hide them?

**SOLVED:**

All I needed to do was to create custom `UITableViewCell` class and then access my cell as Jay Gajjar and Akhilrajtr said. After I just used my method for select/deselect my button.

What I've got:

```
-(void)selectSettings:(AVMMovieButton *)sender
{
    AVMMovieButton *settings = (AVMMovieButton *)sender;
    CGPoint pointInTable = [settings convertPoint:settings.bounds.origin toView:readyTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [readyTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
    AVMMovieCell *cell=(AVMMovieCell *)[readyTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.settingsButton.isSelected) 
    {
        NSLog(@"SELECTED!");

        cell.downloadButton.hidden = YES;
        cell.deleteButton.hidden = YES;
        cell.downLabel.hidden = YES;
        cell.delLabel.hidden = YES;
        cell.playButton.hidden = NO; 
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"UNSELECTED!");
        cell.playButton.hidden = YES;
        cell.downloadButton.hidden = NO;
        cell.deleteButton.hidden = NO;
        cell.downLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.delLabel.hidden = NO;
        NSLog(@"play button %d",cell.playButton.hidden);
    }
    [settings setSelected:!settings.isSelected];
}
```

Hope this can be helpful for somebody else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
-(void)selectSettings:(AVMMovieButton *)sender{

    [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
    CGPoint pointInTable = [sender convertPoint:sender.bounds.origin toView:_tableView];    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [_tableView endUpdates];
    NSLog(@"you just select button");
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for getting `NSIndexPath` for the cell.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr It almost work but with the bug. When I press button on some rows they becomes white :(

Comment: @vendettacore Can you show us the code where you are facing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called when Table get reloaded. In your case, what you have to do is:

```
- (void)button3Method:(id)sender
{
    // Begin UITableView Update
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = // Get cell indexpath for the selected row.

    // Logic for getting the UITableViewCell on which you want hide two buttons.
    // Logic for hiding those two buttons

    // Below line performs reloading of particular UITableViewCell.
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    // End UITaleView Update
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Let me know, if this works for you. Good luck.

Comment: `@[indexPathOfYourCell]` will work in XCode 4.6 OR Higher. Just a note.

Answer (score 1):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
[cell. settings addTarget:self action:@selector(selectSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell. settings.tag=600+indexPath.row;
```

In button IBAction:

```
-(void) selectSettings:(id) sender{    
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    cellMoreButtonIndex=btn.tag;
    YOURCELL *cell=(YOURCELL *)[self.contentTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag-600 inSection:0]];
[settings  setSelected:!settings.isSelected];
if (settings.isSelected) {
    NSLog(@"SELECTED!");

    down.hidden = YES;
    del.hidden = YES;
    downLabel.hidden = YES;
    delLabel.hidden = YES;

   // [self performSelector:@selector(playButtonShow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    playButton.hidden = NO;

}else {
    NSLog(@"UNSELECTED!");


    playButton.hidden = YES;
    down.hidden = NO;
    del.hidden = NO;
    downLabel.hidden = NO;
    delLabel.hidden = NO;

    NSLog(@"play button %d",playButton.hidden);

}
}
```

Comment: how can I get acces to `playButton`,`down` etc ? they are created in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: through cell. Here we are getting a abject of uitableviewcell. Through it you can access any object of that particular cell

Comment: how can I get my buttons through cell object? cell.playButton doesn't work for me

Comment: Have you created your custom uitableviewcell class ??? if you are unaware about custom cell refer: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

add a custom cell and Handle button click event and hide/unhide functionality on cell level