# How to insert values into a UITableViewCell from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UITableView` with 10 cells in it. I have a `UIButton` & `UILabel` inside all the 10 cells. Now if I select a `UIButton` in the 2nd cell, I will navigate to another page and select some values (string values). Now, I want that string to be placed in the `UILabel` of 2nd cell. Likewise, if i select the `UIButton` on 5th cell, I will navigate to another page, select some string and that string has to be placed in the `UILabel` of the 5th cell. How do I insert the values inside the `UILabel` of that particular cell.

Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: use delegate Method. - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Make a property of `NSIndexPath` and set value to it in `didSeclectRow:` method. And after selecting value in next viewcontroller, u can add that value to datasource and reload selected row.

Comment: Do you want to use database or simply using the arrays and strings..

Comment: @Balaji: Using Arrays Only.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: @Vignesh can u show the `cellForRow` code?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: I have got the indexpath of that particular cell. Now how to select that particular cell using the indexpath value.

Comment: @Vignesh: Wait for sometime i will give you the code.

Comment: To select a cell with indexPath u can use `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` @Vignesh

Comment: -(void)brandsBtnTapped: (id)sender
{
    
 UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    
 CGRect buttonFrame = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:self.modifierGroupTableView];
    
 NSIndexpath iPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonFrame.origin];

Comment: @Vignesh check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438220/hide-buttons-in-cell-by-other-button-press-uitableview/27438346#27438346, to see getting indexpath from button action

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: Im using custom cell.             TSModifierGroupTableViewCell *cell = [TSModifierGroupTableViewCell cellForRowAtIndexPath:iPath];
This gives an error. "No Known class method for cellForRowAtIndexpath"

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should invoked on a tableView instance. Not TSModifierGroupTableViewCell .

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: Yes I declared it inside cellForRowAtIndexpath only.

Comment: @Vignesh What code are you using to make the transition between view controllers? Are you using a segue or pushing a view controller or what?

Comment: @Vignesh pls show us the code in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: @LyndseyScott: Im pushing the Viewcontroller

Comment: @Vignesh And are you using Obj-C or Swift? I can write up a suggestion for you if I know.

Comment: @LyndseyScott: Obj-C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend setting that second view controller to contain an instance of the first so you can then manipulate the first view controller's data array from that second view.

For example, in the section of the `FirstViewController` where you create the `SecondViewController` to perform the push (since as you said in the comments, you're pushing the view controller using a `UINavigationController`), also make the `SecondViewController` contain an instance of the `FirstViewController`.

*`FirstViewController` .m:*

```
// Method to handle the push transition
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button {

    // Set the view controller's `selectedRow` property
    // to contain the selected row number as contained in 
    // the button tag in this particular scenario
    self.selectedRow = (int)button.tag;

    // Create an instance of SecondViewController
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Pass the view controller along by setting
    // the secondViewController's firstViewController
    // property to contain self, i.e. the current
    // instance of the FirstViewController
    secondViewController.firstViewController = self;

    // Push to the SecondViewController
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

And in the .h of `SecondViewController`, add the `firstViewController` property such that it's publicly accessible from the `FirstViewController`.

*`SecondViewController` .h:*

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
```

Then in the .m of `SecondViewController`, you can manipulate the array acting as your table's data source in `FirstViewController` as needed, before popping the view.

*`SecondViewController` .m:*

```
// Method called after the string is selected
- (void)stringSelected:(NSString*)string {

    // Update the array to contain the string
    // (or do whatever manipulation to whatever data
    // structure is fitting in your particular case)
    [self.firstViewController.array replaceObjectAtIndex:self.firstViewController.selectedRow withObject:string];

    // To go back to the previous view, pop the view controller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Also, you'll want the `UITableView`'s data source `array` and `selectedRow` property to be contained in the .h of `FirstViewController` so it's publicly accessible from `SecondViewController`.

*`FirstViewController` .h:*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (nonatomic) int selectedRow;
```

And in the .m of `FirstViewController` you want to make sure to reload the table data upon return from the other view so the `UITableView` reflects the updated data.

*`FirstViewController` .m:*

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @Balaji Thanks... I figured it would be helpful to have an explanation of how to pass data while using a UINavigationController all in one place.

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668375/how-to-add-horizontal-spacing-and-vertical-spacing-programmatically-in-ios/27668515#27668515

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellName" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellName"];
}

//Assigning the contents of cell
cell.labelName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.arrCategoryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[cell.buttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonNamePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}

- (void)buttonNamePressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
CGPoint swipepoint = sender.center;
CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:swipepoint toView:self.tableName];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableName indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

[self.tableName cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.defaultRowId = indexPath.row;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentifierName" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

        DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = (DetailsViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
        detailsViewController.defaultrow = self.defaultRowId;

}
```

Now when you navigate to the secondViewController, set the selecting string value to the property of the firstViewController then reload table.

Comment: What is the datatype of defaultRowId here?

Comment: @Vignesh: NSInteger or int whatever may be

Comment: @Vignesh: Why dont you put +1 and answer as correct.

Comment: @Vignesh: If you mark this as correct then others also can easily find the answer

Comment: Balaji: My problem was solved using @Lyndsey Scotts Answer. Thanks for the post.

Comment: @Balaji The main issue here is that the OP was using a UINavigationController and not a storyboard (I'd asked in the comments below his question) so the prepareForSegue method wouldn't be called. Also your code works to pass the data forwards, but the OP wanted to pass data backwards from that "DetailsViewController" to the tableview.

Comment: @LyndseyScott: Thanks again for coming here & posting your feedback.