# How to add horizontal spacing and vertical spacing programmatically in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created an app in ios 8. In that I have 4 labels which are available as vertically (it should change the position for certain conditions), I have disabled auto layout and setting constraints programmatically. Now, the problem is however I can set constraints for horizontal and vertical positions, width and height, I could not find any way to add constraints for horizontal and vertical spacing between the labels.

Can anyone please help me to do this.

So far I have the following code:

```
NSArray *constraint_V_WebUrl = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[weburl(31)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:contentDictionary];
    NSArray *constraint_H_WebUrl = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[weburl(196)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:contentDictionary];
    NSArray *constraint_POS_H_WebUrl = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-13-[weburl]" options:0 metrics:nil views:contentDictionary];
[self.cardDetails addConstraints:constraint_POS_V_WebUrl];
    [self.cardDetails addConstraints:constraint_POS_H_WebUrl];
[self.cardDetails addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.weburl attribute:NSla relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.cardDetails attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin multiplier:1 constant:0.0]];
```

Code above works fine. But I want to set horizontal and vertical spacing between the labels.

Answer (score 5):

You can use both visual format and code format for defining constraints. 
Visual format has many restrictions and not applicable to all cases.

In your case you can use (horizontal spacing):

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:YourViewAtLeft
 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
 toItem:YourViewAtRight attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
 multiplier:1.0 constant:ValueOfSpacing];

// Paste your view names and constraint value.
```

And then add this constraint with `addCostraint`.

Comment: I want to move the label when the parent view size is increased. For example, If the parent view size increases by 30px then the label also should increase the y position by 30 px.. is it possible?

Comment: Just connect label's `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` with parent's `NSLayoutAttributeRight`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a constraint to place a subview at a fixed distance( horizontal or vertical ) from another. Just remember that when constraining two sibling views, the constraint should be added to the parent view.

Example: let's say you have 2 labels, label1 and label2, both children of a UIView called parentView. Create the constraint with label2 and label1 as items, label2 left equal to label1 right, multiplier 1 and constant equal to the desired horizontal spacing. 
Then add the constraint to parentView, not to either of the labels.

Example code:

```
 [ parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: label2 
                                                         attribute: NSLayoutAttribueLeft                                 
                                                         relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem: label1  
                                                         attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight 
                                                        multiplier: 1 
                                                          constant: LABEL_SPACING ] ];
```

Comment: I want to move the label when the parent view size is increased. For example, If the parent view size increases by 30px then the label also should increase the y position by 30 px.. is it possible?

Comment: just constrain this label (with a fixed # of points) to the bottom edge and constrain its height and you'll get this behaviour in the Y axis...

Answer (score 1):

Balaji

I had a similar problem but was able to fix it by creating constraints in the storyboard between the labels and linking them (the constraints) up to IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraints. By checking for different screen sizes, the constraints can be modified in code.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* verticalSpace1;
```

And then, in viewWillAppear...

```
if (height > x) { // x would just be below the height you wanted to change it for 
    _verticalSpace1.constant = 20;
}
```

This changes the spacing, which I had previously set in storyboard to 8, up to 20. Hopefully this solves your problem.